Plotting input and output characteristics of diode circuits
I'm new to microelectronics and I'm having a bit of trouble with plotting the input and output characteristics of diode circuits.
Initially I practiced plotting the circuit circled in red. I do not have the correct answer to this question.
Then, I found a similar question with only the diode reversed (labeled c), and practiced that one as well, but the plot I ended up drawing differs from the answer I was given, and I cannot figure out why. I have attached my thought process as well as the answer given for the second circuit. Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance.



Try to see that for example when Vin = 0V. No current is flowing in the circuit (diode blocks the current). But the Vout voltage is not equal to 0V.  Notice the now ( for Vin = 0V) VB is in parallel with Vout. Thus, Vout = -VB. And to get Vout = 0V the input voltage must be equal to VB. Because Vout = Vin - VB.

Ahh I see! Thank you for the help! :)
